# Red language application executable crashing while interpreted one works

Tags: windows, executable, red

I am trying to create a small gui application having about 30 fields where users can enter data and a button which will save the data. It works all right when I run it with command:

```
red-063 myappl.r
```

Then I created its executable using following command:

```
red-063 -c -r -t windows myappl.r
```

However, this executable crashes whenever save button is pressed. There is no error message. On running in Linux using `wine`, I get following message on crashing:

```
*** Runtime Error err:seh:raise_exception Unhandled exception code c0000005 flags 0 addr 0x417374
```

The application needs `'View` hence cannot be compiled for Linux.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to use the **-d** debug option when compiling, but bear in mind that Red is still alpha

Comment: If this does not help, generate a minimal program that shows the crash and submit it on https://gitter.im/red/bugs

Comment: It is still crashing without any error message.

Comment: The proper place to raise bug reports is on [Red's issue tracker](https://github.com/red/red/issues).  But there (as here), you should always provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: While trying to make a minimal example I removed many print and probe commands which I had included for debugging and that seems to have cured the problem! Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Please report it as crash with code tho on bug tracker. It's important for red's development